# Using polygons made by Generate Service Areas as input feature class in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst, service-area

In ModelBuilder, I used "generate service areas" tool and made service area polygons.

I want to use them as input feature and connect to other geoproccessing tool, but I cannot.

Service area polygons remains as white　and I get:

> Error Message 000918

what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong geoprocessing tool. You need to use the [Make Service Area Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Make_Service_Area_Layer/00480000000p000000/) tool and then [Solve](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Solve/00480000000r000000/) tool.

Use [Generate Service Areas](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Generate_Service_Areas/00480000001w000000/) (which is in the Server toolset) only if you are setting up a geoprocessing service; it will simplify the setup process. So, it's only for publishing a service on the ArcGIS Server. Otherwise, for Desktop usage, use Make Service Area Layer.